# I'm trying to have a hide series button on my highchart but it makes the chart disappear

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

When I click on my button the series briefly disappears then the screen appears to refresh then the whole chart disappears, am I missing something simple.  Please see the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {  
$('#container').highcharts({  
chart: {  
type: 'line'  , 
zoomType: 'x'
},  

xAxis: {  type: 'datetime',
labels: {
formatter: function () {return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e/%m/%Y <br/> %H:%M:%S', this.value);
}
 },

tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    gridLineWidth: 1

    },  
    yAxis: {  
title: {
        text: engUnit,
 }
    },  
    series: [{  
    name: userID,
      data: <%= chartData%>  
    },

     {
      name: 'High Alarm Value',
      data: <%= chartDataMax%>  
    },

     {
     name: 'Low Alarm Value',
    data: <%= chartDataMin%>  
    }

    ]  
  });  

var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    $button = $('#button');
$button.click(function () {
    var series = chart.series[1];
    var series1 = chart.series[2];
    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
        series1.hide();
        $button.html('Show series');
    } else {
        series.show();
        series1.show();
        $button.html('Hide series');
    }
       });
});  
</script>
```

the part where i display my chart on the screen using a master page

```
<button id="button" class="autocompare">Hide series</button>
<div id="container" style="height: 376px; width: 880px; position: relative; left: 4px; margin-top: -210px; top: 231px;" >
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "the whole chart", do you mean that nothing is visible at all, or do you mean that the axis labels no longer show? If the latter, try adding a min and max to each axis.  Secondly - what is the point? Why do you want the user to be able to show an empty chart with no data...?

Comment: @jlbriggs I think this button is to show/hide alarms - notice three series in options. The code above should work, do you have any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @PawełFus Ah, right. In that case, it seems this would be smoother to accomplish by using the linkedTo property, and linking the two alarm series together, and naming the series 'Alarms' or something similar - that way there is only one legend entry for the two series, and when clicked, it toggles both series' visibility

Comment: Thanks for response, you are right there will always be 1 series visible - the button does remove the series but then I get a white screen where the graph was.

Comment: Still, how about my question? I mean, open JavaScript console and let us know about errors there.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, been away from office - I don't get any errors from JavaScript console!

Answer (score 0):

I was obviously having a bad day last week.  The reason it was disappearing was due to postback on a control I am using to select a date.

Once I click the show/hide button, the button posts back and causes the screen to refresh.